# How to get the button onclick text by using css or xpath selector

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

I am not sure how can we get button onclick text by using css/xpath selector. Below is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-sm no-redirect ph" onclick="showNumber('11111111122 / 002-26688<br>18000000000', 'DIM')">
    <span>ABC</span>
</button>
```

I want to extract the numbers "11111111122 / 002-26688
18000000000" from the onclick attribute of the button.

Please help.

Comment: Where is showing the number once you click that button ?

Comment: When I click the button another pop up window appear and number shown over that window

Comment: For that you have to locate the element over there after click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do it - one would be like this:

`'//*[contains(@onclick, "showNumber")]'`

`'//*[contains(@onclick, "showNumber")]/*'`

or simply

`//@onclick`

and then clean it up with regex, depends on what the rest of the source, and how it parses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with

    response.xpath('//*[contains(@onclick, 'showNumber')]').extract()
but it gives me an error like invalid syntax

Comment: You have to use double quotes specificifically around the "showNumber" part @michael

Comment: Sorry I fixed my example

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath to click the button

```
//button[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right btn-sm no-redirect ph']
```

And you have to locate the element, to get the text displays after button click

Answer (score 0):

```
response.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right btn-sm no-redirect ph']/@onclick").extract_first()
```

Now you will get the output "showNumber('11111111122 / 002-26688
18000000000', 'DIM')"

Then you have to convert it to string and trim it to get your required numbers.